# rsyslogd: how to send messages to user pseudo console

Tags: linux

I set up my rsyslogd.conf setting so:

```
auth,authpriv.*                 username
```

but username does not get the messages (in (all) his pseudo-terminals i.e Gnome terminals).
My questions related to this:

1. should the user see the messages? if yes, what could be the cause, that the user does not get the messages.
2. if no, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `username` syntax is deprecated in rsyslog. Use `:omusrmsg:username` instead.

If it still does not work:

rsyslog uses the `/var/run/utmp` file to find a list of the user's ttys; terminal emulators have to add themselves to that file, and this requires sufficient privileges (the file is usually *not* world-writable). X11-based terminal emulators are different from system login programs, in that they start with the user's, not root's, privileges.

Use `pinky`, `finger`, `w`, or `who` to list the contents of *utmp*. If they do not list any "pts/X" entries belonging to pseudo-terminals:

1. First make sure `/var/run/utmp` exists, is owned by the `utmp` group and is writable by that group. If not, run

   ```
   # chown :utmp /var/run/utmp && chmod ug=rw,o=r /var/run/utmp
   ```
2. Then check if your terminal emulator has sufficient privileges to write to that file – namely, the *setgid* bit and correct group ownership:

   ```
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 root utmp 1.3M May 25  2012 /usr/bin/urxvt
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 root utmp 475K Nov 26 16:54 /usr/bin/xterm
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 root utmp  15K Nov 13 00:36 /usr/lib/vte/gnome-pty-helper
   ```

   Note: GNOME Terminal uses a separate `gnome-pty-helper` tool to perform utmp changes.

   If any are missing, run:

   ```
   # chown :utmp /usr/lib/vte/gnome-pty-helper \
       && chmod g+s /usr/lib/vte/gnome-pty-helper
   ```
3. Make sure `rsyslogd` is running as an account that is allowed to write to users' ttys. If necessary, add it to the `tty` group.
4. In some distributions, check if the SELinux or AppArmor policy allows the utmp updates.

Comment: After changing to the new format `:omusrmsg:username` I restarted the rsyslogd (`/etc/init.d/rsyslogd restart`). Of course I checked also step 2 (and I get entries with gnome-pty-helper in the response to `w`). The problem is that nothing comes (the same syslogd facilities are logged also in a file).

Comment: any ideas on how to debug further?

Comment: Which user is `rsyslogd` running as?

Comment: user: `syslog`. Parameters used by rsyslogd: `-c5`. And it is a Ubuntu 12.04  system, probably using AppArmor.

Comment: Actually it is the `gnome-terminal`, that shows up in the `w` output.

Comment: Try adding that user to the `tty` group: `gpasswd -a syslog tty` – then restart rsyslogd.

Comment: `syslog` is now a user in the `tty` group, but unfortunately no effect....